# Site gets slow after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my page/site is gets crazy slow after ajax call. I need to restart browser to fix problem. 
It's works fine on "localhost" but not on the live/remote server.

After some troubleshooting I think the problem is when I call my functions "update_actions" and "update_notes" that loading content to different `<div>`. I call this function on page load and it works. But when I call this function again after eg. a ajax call, to update the divs content site "crashes". What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  update_actions();
});

$(document).on('click', '.action_link', function(e) {
  var name = e.currentTarget;
  var data_string = name.getAttribute("data-name");

  $.post("sql_action.php", { action_id: data_string, }, function(response) {
    update_actions();
  });
});

function update_actions() {
  $('#result_actions').load('dia_load_actions.php?area=1&d=<?php echo $dia_decrypt; ?> ');
  $('#develop_actions').load('dia_load_actions.php?area=2&d=<?php echo $dia_decrypt; ?>'); $('#competens_actions').load('dia_load_actions.php?area=3&d=<?php echo $dia_decrypt; ?>');
}

function update_notes() {
  $('#area_notes_1').load('dia_load_notes.php?area=1&d=<?php echo $dia_encrypt; ?>');
  $('#area_notes_2').load('dia_load_notes.php?area=2&d=<?php echo $dia_encrypt; ?>');
  $('#area_notes_3').load('dia_load_notes.php?area=3&d=<?php echo $dia_encrypt; ?>');
  <?php if($dialogue_type==2){ ?>
  $('#area_notes_4').load('dia_load_notes.php?area=4&d=<?php echo $dia_encrypt; ?>');
  <?php } ?>
  $('#area_notes_5').load('dia_load_notes.php?area=5&d=<?php echo $dia_encrypt; ?>');
  $('#area_notes_6').load('dia_load_notes.php?area=6&d=<?php echo $dia_encrypt; ?>');
}
```

Comment: You're making *far* too many AJAX requests too quickly and flooding your server. You need to aggregate all of those requests in to a single one and update the DOM on the client side from the response.

Comment: Thanks for a fast reply @RoryMcCrossan but knowlege abouit this is not great! Update the DOM?

Comment: The DOM is the Document Object Model, basically a representation of your HTML Page in your browsers memory.

Comment: Is it better to do a ajax call that return an json array with all the content and then $('#area_notes_5').html(array[4])? Will this solve my problem?

Comment: load() method is deprecated and removed in jQuery version 3.0.